# How can i crop image using the HTML5 canvas and JavaScript in order to crop an image offline?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, grails, html5-canvas, cordova

There are several tools out there on the Internet to crop an image using JavaScript and PHP but unfortunately if we intend for our app to be strictly offline there is no server side PHP scripting that we can rely on so to achieve this we must use the HTML5 canvas and JavaScript in order to crop an image offline.

Answer (score 2):

**If the image originated on the local domain, then you can easily crop it with html canvas.**

But, if the image originated from another domain, you will run into CORS security errors:  http://code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity

If needed, you can also scale up/down as you are cropping.

Here's example code to use canvas' `drawImage` to crop an image:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
       crop();
    }
    img.src=document.getElementById("source").src;

    function crop(){
        // this takes a 105x105px crop from img at x=149/y=4
        // and copies that crop to the canvas
        ctx.drawImage(img,149,4,105,105,0,0,105,105);
        // this uses the canvas as the src for the cropped img element
        document.getElementById("cropped").src=canvas.toDataURL();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <img id="source" width=400 height=234 src="localImage.png">
    <img id="cropped" width=105 height=105>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=105 height=105></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can write `img.onload=crop;` rather than the inline function.